# Flask-SQLAlchemy issue with {Class}.query.all() request not retrieving all datas from table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a small Flask project in Python 3.6.

I am trying to work with SQLAlchemy to manage a small SQLite3 database and I encounter some issues.

Here is the Model I work with (database variable is called 'db') :

```
class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    deadline = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    date_closed = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    owner = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    state = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default='0')
    priority = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default='0')
    project = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

I then inserted the following stuff just to try :

```
post_1 = Task(title='Task 1', owner='Guillaume', project='First Project')
post_2 = Task(title='Task 2', owner='Guillaume', project='First Project')
post_3 = Task(title='Task 3', owner='Jiji', project='Second Project')
```

I can see that my datas are inserted well when I check the Task table.

The problem is when I try to query my database to retrieve all its datas, I use the following command after importing my Task class:

```
Task.query.all()
```

I thought I would just get as a response a list with all the datas for my 3 posts but I get the following which I don't understand why :

```
[<Task 1>, <Task 2>, <Task 3>]
```

Can someone explain this and help me to get the list with all datas ? :)

Comment: You get list of such items, because your defined SQLAlchemy model `Task` implicitly derives `__repr__` method from `db.Model` class. As a result, each item is represented as string: `<model_class_name primary_key>`. `primary_key` is in this case your `id` field.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Flask-SQLAlchemy specifically, but as a sqlalchemy user, I think there is chances that each item in your list is a `Task` instance exposing actual data via attributes.

Try this to see available attributes:

```
>>> dir(Task.query.all()[0])
```

Something like this should show you your data:

```
for task in Task.query.all():
    print(task.id, task.title, task.content, task.date_created)  # etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you wanted list of title for example you could use list comprehension

```
titles = [T.title for T in Task.query.all()]
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, it turned out that I needed to specify `primary_key=True` in the model.
After that, all the data was loaded.